# Facebook Send/Like buttons not working on my site page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, send

When I clicked the LIKE or SEND buttons on my site for this link, I get this error:

The page at http://aftersqool.com/a?id=C217EE could not be reached.

Strangely, the page is loading without any issues. The page even has the og tags that Facebook requires.

Anyone know why Facebook is giving this error? What should I do to get the buttons working?

Thanks!

Gus Collazo
AfterSqool.com

Comment: That page is _not_ “loading without any issues”, at least not right now – I get a 500 response code, and FB’s debug tool sees the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use the Send Button if you’re using Facebook as a Page instead of a Personal Profile.

The Send Button **only** works with `XFBML` version of the Like Button; it **doesn't work** with the iFrame version of the Like Button, per Facebook’s announcement

One more important thing is to provide your facebook page's `URL` in send and like button. It will defiantly fix it.

If your facebook page `URL` is: `http://www.facebook.com/aftersqool`

put this code in it

```html
/*put this code in body*/
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id))
    return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


/*put this code in site where you want to add it*/

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/AfterSqool" data-width="450"        data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Smit Shilu solution to work. I had to remove xfmb=1 to get my buttons to work. Full solution here.

http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.ca/2013/09/facebook-likesend-button-not-working.html